# R, Leaflet polygons add black borders

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, border, polygon

I would like to add a black border around my polygons. See the image below what I have got so far.

[image]

I used this code. I dont know how I could include a zip file so its reproducible.

```
library("rgdal")
library("leaflet")

 amsterdam.districts <- shapefile("~/R/Shiny/Shapefiles/sd2010zw_region.shp")
 amsterdam.districts <- spTransform(amsterdam.districts, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
 amsterdam.districts$STADSDEELN<- c("Centrum","Westpoort","West","Nieuw West","Zuid","Oost","Noord","Zuidoost")

 amsterdam.districts$SDNUMMER=as.factor(amsterdam.districts$SDNUMMER) 
 factpal=colorFactor(brewer.pal(n = 11, name ="Spectral") , amsterdam.districts$SDNUMMER) 

   leaflet() %>%
     addPolygons(
       data =amsterdam.districts, 
       stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
       color = "grey",
       fillColor = ~factpal(SDNUMMER),
       layerId = amsterdam.districts@data$STADSDEELN)%>%
     addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 1))
```

Thanks for reading!

Martijn

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(mapview)
library(RColorBrewer)

factpal <- colorFactor(brewer.pal(n = 11, name ="Spectral") , gadmCHE$NAME_1) 

leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = gadmCHE, 
    stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = "black", opacity = 1,
    fillColor = ~factpal(gadmCHE$NAME_1)) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 1))
```

You simply need to set `stroke = TRUE` and `color = "black"` to get the borders. Note that I also set `opacity = 1` to prevent semitransparent borders.

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy, thank you very much!! @TimSalabim